# Create A Metabox For A Custom Field

Tags: posts, custom-field, metabox

I add videos to my WordPress posts' video format by using custom fields. I was wondering if there is any way to create a meta box in post editor (like excerpt or something) for that specific custom field. Just a text area to add iframe code. For example the custom field is a embed-video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will create a metabox for you to enter a video code.

```
    //Creating a MetaBox for Posts to enter Video Code.
add_action('add_meta_boxes','video_meta_box');
function video_meta_box(){
    add_meta_box('video_box_id', 'Enter Video ' , 'video_box_cb','post','normal','default');
}
function video_box_cb($post){
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_box',true);

    echo '<textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="video_box", name="video_box">';
        echo $value;
    echo '</textarea>';
}

add_action('save_post','save_video_box');
function save_video_box($post_id){
    $box_data = $_POST['video_box'];
    update_post_meta($post_id,'video_box',$box_data);
}
```

Use this code to render this code within your theme.

```
<?php
    $custom_values = get_post_custom($post->ID);
    echo '<p> Video CODE: '.$custom_values['video_box'][0].'</p>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks!! It worked! Can you tell me why there is [0] after ['video_box']

Comment: Glad it worked... Please mark it as accepted answer on the left side of the answer.

[0] signifies first element of the array. You can do `var_dump($custom_values['video_box']);` to see what's in the array and what to be retrieved.

Comment: I marked this thread as resolved. However, is it possible to do this with a custom field?

Comment: Yes, this can be done with a custom field too. But since you need to have dedicated box for entering come custom then making a metabox is a good idea.

Comment: Yes, it is, but there are more than 100 posts already with that custom_field so creating a meta box for field will be a better idea. Plus, I'll also learn how to do that ;) Please explain that too..